# How do I merge two data frames in pandas on a common column which have similar values (but not the same)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I am trying to merge two dataframes in pandas on a common column showing names of the geographical area. The column has similar values but not the same. For example, the value in one DataFrame is `London` whereas the other one is `London / Greater London` - they are treated as different values but should be treated as the same value when merging.

```
In[1]: 
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['London', 2], ['Bristol', 3], ['Liverpool', 6]], columns=['Area', 'B'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['London / Greater London', 7], ['Bristol_', 9], ['Liverpool / Liverpool', 1]], columns=['Area', 'B'])
df_merged = pd.merge(df1, df2, on="Area", indicator=True, how='outer')
df_merged

Out[1]: 
                      Area  B_x  B_y      _merge
0                   London  2.0  NaN   left_only
1                  Bristol  3.0  NaN   left_only
2                Liverpool  6.0  NaN   left_only
3  London / Greater London  NaN  7.0  right_only
4                 Bristol_  NaN  9.0  right_only
5    Liverpool / Liverpool  NaN  1.0  right_only
```

The ideal output would be something like the below:

```
Out[1]: 
                      Area  B_x  B_y      _merge
0                   London  2.0  7.0   both
1                  Bristol  3.0  9.0   both
2                Liverpool  6.0  1.0   both
```

Is there a way to merge these two dataframes based on a certain level of similarities in values so that `London` and `London / Greater London` values are treated as the same value? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can first create two `arrays` containing the indices of overlapping `Area` and `City` using `np.where()`. I used a `list comprehension` to check if each `City` was present `in` the list of `Areas` and save the index.

**Note**: This only works if the `string` of an `Area` contains the `City` `string`. (i.e. `London` is only matched with `London / Greater London` if this `area` contains the word `London`.

The code:

```
# Alter the column names B (present in both dfs to B_x and B_y )
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['London', 2], ['Bristol', 3], ['Liverpool', 6]], columns=['Area', 'B_x'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['London / Greater London', 7], ['Bristol_', 9], ['Liverpool / Liverpool', 1]], columns=['Area', 'B_y'])

# Create indices of matching string patterns
i, j = np.where([[city in area for area in df2['Area'].values] for city in df1['Area'].values])

# Create new dataframe with found indices
pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack([df1.iloc[i], df2.iloc[j]]), columns=df1.columns.append(df2.columns))
```

**Result**

```
    Area        B_x     Area                    B_y
0   London      2   London / Greater London     7
1   Bristol     3   Bristol_                    9
2   Liverpool   6   Liverpool / Liverpool       1
```